# Referenciar objeto não estático em um método estático

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Boa noite, preciso referenciar um componente `PlaceHolder` `Asp.Net` em um método estático no `code-behind` `C#`, esse método é chamado via `AJAX` pelo `front-end` vejam o código:

Chamada do método pelo front-end Form aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallCsharpFunction(andamento_id) {
         try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Processo.aspx/AtuarNoProcesso',
                data: "{'AndamentoID':'" + andamento_id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: location.reload(true), 
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) { }
    }
</script>
```

O Método no Code-Behind C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AtuarNoProcesso(int AndamentoID)
{   
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal
    {
          Text =  Andamento.Make_Table_Html(Convert.ToInt32(AndamentoID)) });
    }
}
```

Mas recebe a mensagem `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"` no componente `PlaceHolder1`. 
Como faço o método enxergar o componente PlaceHolder1?

Comment: Não dá !!!! ..... vai ter que usar outra forma! o que pretende fazer?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Andamento é uma classe com uma função que retorna um string "Make_Table_Html" que monta o html uma tabela com nomes de pessoas

Comment: Se o método precisa acessar um membro de instância ele não deveria ser estático.

Comment: @Evandro retorna um `JSON` e trabalhe a informação no seu front, já que está utilizando `Ajax`! diretamente isso não é possivel, ou até, retorna o html mudando o retorno `dataType:'html'` no seu `ajax`! tem duas opções ai.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou tentar modelar retornando um JSON, vc teria um exemplo em código para orientar-me.

Comment: @Evandro um exemplo: https://cbsa.com.br/post/web-service---retornar-json-com-aspnetc.aspx

Comment: @VirgilioNovic assim vai funcionar no retorno  `$('.resultado').text(data.d);` eu monto o html, vou testar e posto aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme dica do pessoal montei a tabela `html` com as informações no retorno `JSON` da chamada `Ajax`, vejam como ficou:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData(andamento_id) {
        var $tbl = $('#tbl');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Andamento.aspx/GetComentarioAndamento',
            data: "{'AndamentoID':'" + andamento_id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + data.d[i].ComentarioTexto
                            + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].DataHoraComentario
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + "<div class='row centered'><div class='user-block'><img src='"
                            + data.d[i].FotoProfile + "' data-toggle='tooltip' title='"
                            + data.d[i].NomeAdvogado + "' class='img-circle img-bordered-sm'></div></div>"
                            + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

//tabela
<table id="tbl" class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```